# How to update textview text which is update in service class

Tags: android, android-layout, service, background

I have developed an app with `start`, `pause`, `resume` and `finish` buttons.

It works properly in the activity using **thread and handler**.

If the user clicks on the `start button` a thread is started and displays `textviewHH:MM:SS time` and the rest of the buttons work correctly as well.

**Problem:**

If the activity goes to background then **how do I update the textview time?** I have made services for this task but, how do I take the **response from services to UI?**

Please, could you give me any idea of how to do it or any other possible solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create `CustomBroadcast`

Here is sample code.
Try this, it will work..

In **YourService.Java**

```
public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.example.tracking.updateprogress";
intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In **YourActivity.Java**

```
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(YourService.BROADCAST_ACTION));

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //Update Your UI here.. 
                updateUI();      
        }
}
```

You can also pass data in `Intent`.

Comment: how to used stop and pause in services?

Comment: start,**resume**,stop work proper. how to **resume** services? means?

Comment: how to pause services when i click on pause button?

Comment: Service can't pause/resume [Check Service life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a simple `new Thread(new Runnable() {...})` within the Activity you can run UI manipulations with the `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { // your UI modify method })` Acitvity method. If the Activity go to the background the Thread is still running.